# Python PyWinauto issue

Tags: python-3.x, pywinauto

I am working on a project where the Jenkins pipeline triggers the python gui in a remote desktop server to install and connfigure some applications. However the below command always throws error at first instance with an error as "

```
No windows for that process could be found
```

app = Application(backend='uia').start(cmd_line=baseConfig.obConfigEXEPath + batchCommand).

However when i run it manually next time,,it opens up the windows and test cases gets passed. What might be the issue

I have tried putting using app.connect below the same command but still not working

```
app = Application(backend='uia').start(cmd_line=baseConfig.obConfigEXEPath + batchCommand)
app.connect(path = baseConfig.obConfigEXEPath)
```

Also i have replaced backend='uia' with backend='win32', but it did not work too.It came up with error as "No windows for that process could be found"

Comment: I think it's not about the backend= portion. it's the program you are trying to open from the start() function. what is within this? >> baseConfig.obConfigEXEPath + batchCommand

Comment: But why it is running the second time when i enter into the windows server using rdp and execute the same commands

Comment: you mean there are two instances? I don't see anything amiss from the info you provided above. But like from my answers below, if you are able to start the application, you already have the handle, don't have to send app.connect() again.

Comment: Full error traceback is always better than just error message text. Please provide full information including values in strings. If some part of value is internal information, you can replace it by some XXXX symbols or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Just note that app.connect() is to connect with apps that already been opened.
There are two ways. either by the exe name or by the window name as shown below,

`app.connect(path='ABC.exe')` or `app.connect(title='ABC')`

I see you are trying with just baseConfig.obConfigEXEPath as the exe path, what is the batchCommand for? If you have the exact EXE name and it is visible from the environment variable just call it directly like this,

```
app = Application().start(baseConfig.obConfigEXEPath)
```

Comment: We are executing this batch command after launching the window .We give the credentials to open it as shown below:                                                                                         

batchCommand = ' -AL UN="%s" PW="%s" ODBC="%s" -DTGAPPLY' \
                % (baseConfig.obConfigUserName, 'password', baseConfig.OnBaseDSNName)

# Launch OnBase Configuration
app = Application(backend='uia').start(cmd_line=baseConfig.obConfigEXEPath + batchCommand)


baseConfig.obConfigEXEPath is the path to the executable file in the windows 10 server

Comment: I've a question, if you run the cmd line on the command prompt does it open your exe successfully?

Comment: Sorry..i did not understand..How can i run the cmd line ? If i execute the python script manually the second time i enter the server and execute the commands through command prompt,,it passes everything.

Comment: okay correct me if I'm wrong. the script automatically run once, it prompts error, no application is opened. you run the SAME script manually once, no error and application open successfully. is that right?

Comment: Yes you are correct..

Comment: baseConfig.obConfigEXEPath<< Is this the full path or just the EXE name?

Comment: Its the full path including the exe name at the end..

Comment: ah alright, I'm asking all the questions because I'm ruling out few possibilities of environment path issue which don't seem to be the case. try launching the app through your cmd line. open command prompt and directly paste this whole section baseConfig.obConfigEXEPath + batchCommand. See if you require just once or two times to launch it successfully.

Comment: if you can launch it successfully in one go, means it's something got to do with pywinauto. alternatively, you will have to execute a batch file to open the app. and then only call app.connect() to get the handle of the already-opened application.

Comment: Hi, baseConfig.obConfigEXEPath + batchCommand is written in the python code and the directories are mapped in two different python files.  How can i run it directly in the command prompt? baseconfig refers to the config file present in another directory which is imported in the current file.obConfigEXEPath  is mapped in the baseconfig file .batchCommand  is mapped in the python file in the current directory where i am executing this python script.

Comment: Any comments on this...I could see the application launched in the processes but the windows not getting launched

Comment: After putting exceptions,,now i found that i was able to launch the app but the windows are not found..It throws at this with the message "No windows for that process could be found"                              
         app.top_window().set_focus()